# magit: how to set default username?

Tags: magit, git

Is it possible to set a default username (i.e.: my Github user name) for magit? It is prompting for the user every time I have to push a commit.

Don't know if this may help with the answer, but I already have my username and my e-mail in `~/.gitconfig` as per magit's manual:

> The default is determined by the `user.name` and `user.email` git configuration settings.

Comment: [Meta discussion about the topicality of this question](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74/questions-where-emacs-is-only-anecdotal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`user.name` in your .gitconfig is only for authorship of commits, and not used for authentication. It seems you are using password authentication before pushing to github.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Fixed it with: git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git