# magit "empty ident name (for <(null)>) not allowed" on commit

Tags: magit

On Windows 10, after staging a file in magit and attempting to commit it I get this error message instead

```
empty ident name (for <(null)>) not allowed
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message occurs because magit can not find the `user.name` and `user.email` git configuration settings. These can be set by [magit: how to set default username?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/487/magit-how-to-set-default-username)

The problem is when this is set globally. Git for Windows will put this in `~/.gitconfig` but the default location for your `~` as described in [Where can I find my .emacs file for Emacs running on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189490/where-can-i-find-my-emacs-file-for-emacs-running-on-windows) will be in `AppData/..`

You can see that it can't find the global config file by `M-x magit-command config --list` but the same command run from Git for Windows `git config --list` displays the correct user.name and user.email.

I fixed this by setting the `HOME` variable to `%USERPFOFILE%`